# Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI' (0x10d249f78) to 'NSArray'

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, crash, nsarray

This is my code :

```
if let responseDic = response as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                {
                    var temp = Array<Store>.init()

                    var dataDic = responseDic["data"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                    if dataDic != nil {

                        for storeList in dataDic!["stores"] as! NSArray {
                                if let store = storeList as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                                {
                                    temp.append((Store(dictionary: store)))
                                }
                            }
                    }
```

I'm getting crash error : Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI' (0x10d249f78) to 'NSArray' (0x10d24b008). for this line : `for storeList in dataDic!["stores"] as! NSArray`

This is my response Structure:

```
{
  "data": {
    "stores": {
      "items": [
        {...}]
}
}
```

Comment: It means that `dataDic!["stores"]` is in fact a `Dictionary`, not an `Array`. You misunderstood the structure of your response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert this

```
for storeList in dataDic!["stores"] as! NSArray
```

to

```
if let dic = dataDic!["stores"] as? [String:Any] {}
```